# How to access the values of an array from a helper function outside of scope

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects with key value pairs defined within a class in the ngOnInit method. I am trying to access the values of that array from a function outside of the class without duplicating the array in the function as I do not want to have to define the array and then re write it again in the function.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
staff: Array<any> = [""];


constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bmrForm = this._fb.group({
      staff: [""]
    });


this.staff = [
      {
        item_id: "MGS",
        item_text: "Michael Gary Scott"
      },
      {
        item_id: "DKS",
        item_text: "Dwight Kurt Schrute"
      }
    ];



}
  onSearchClicked() {
    expression(this.bmrForm);
  }
}
function expression(bmrForm: FormGroup) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.staff.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.staff[i].item_id);
  }

}
```

**I have tried to recreate the problem here :**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcjqq2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

When I try to call the `expression();` function in the `onSearchClicked()` method I get property of staff undefined.

I know that if  I duplicate the `staff` in the `expression` function I can get it's value however I was hopin to achieve this without duplicating my code.

Any solutions for this would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your code in the Angular way. The function `expression()` should be inside the `AppComponent` class and access the express function inside `onSearchClicked()` this way `this.expression(this.bmrForm)`. I've updated your code and it works now.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  staff: Array<any> = [""];
  bmrForm: FormGroup;
  dropdownSettings: any = {};
 ShowFilter = false;
    limitSelection = false;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bmrForm = this._fb.group({
      staff: [""]
    });
    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: "item_id",
      textField: "item_text",
      selectAllText: "Select All",
      unSelectAllText: "Un-Select All",
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
                  allowSearchFilter: this.ShowFilter
    };

    this.staff = [
      {
        item_id: "MGS",
        item_text: "Michael Gary Scott"
      },
      {
        item_id: "DKS",
        item_text: "Dwight Kurt Schrute"
      }
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.staff.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.staff[i].item_id);
    }
  }
  onSearchClicked() {
    console.log(this.bmrForm.value);
    this.expression(this.bmrForm);
  }
       toogleShowFilter() {
        this.ShowFilter = !this.ShowFilter;
        this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { allowSearchFilter: this.ShowFilter });
    }


    handleLimitSelection() {
        if (this.limitSelection) {
            this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { limitSelection: 2 });
        } else {
            this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { limitSelection: null });
        }
    }

  expression(bmrForm: FormGroup) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.staff.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.staff[i].item_id);
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`bind` `expression` to a class context when you call it

```
onSearchClicked() {
  console.log(this.bmrForm.value);
  expression.bind(this, this.bmrForm);
}
```

More explanation:

`expression.bind(this, this.bmrForm);` means - run function `expression` using `this` (that refers to `AppComponent`) context with a single argument `this.bmrForm`

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvmhup?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be to encapsulate your helper function in an object. Here your code with the added functionality:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  staff: Array<any> = [""];
  myHelper : Helper;
  bmrForm: FormGroup;
  dropdownSettings: any = {};
 ShowFilter = false;
    limitSelection = false;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bmrForm = this._fb.group({
      staff: [""]
    });
    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: "item_id",
      textField: "item_text",
      selectAllText: "Select All",
      unSelectAllText: "Un-Select All",
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
                  allowSearchFilter: this.ShowFilter
    };

    this.staff = [
      {
        item_id: "MGS",
        item_text: "Michael Gary Scott"
      },
      {
        item_id: "DKS",
        item_text: "Dwight Kurt Schrute"
      }
    ];
    this.myHelper = new Helper();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.staff.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.staff[i].item_id);
    }
  }
  onSearchClicked() {
    console.log(this.bmrForm.value);
    this.myHelper.expression(this.bmrForm,this.staff);
  }
       toogleShowFilter() {
        this.ShowFilter = !this.ShowFilter;
        this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { allowSearchFilter: this.ShowFilter });
    }


    handleLimitSelection() {
        if (this.limitSelection) {
            this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { limitSelection: 2 });
        } else {
            this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { limitSelection: null });
        }
    }
}

class Helper {

  expression(bmrForm: FormGroup, staff: Array<any>) {
  for (let i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
    console.log(staff[i].item_id);
  }

}


}
```

That way, if the number of helper functions grow, you can define the class elsewhere and start importing it where it is needed.
PD: `bmrForm: FormGroup` doesn't seem to be needed in `expression()`

Answer (score -1):

Move the `expression` function within the class.

```
onSearchClicked() {
    this.expression(this.bmrForm);
  }

expression(bmrForm: FormGroup) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.staff.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.staff[i].item_id);
  }
}
```